# iphone, how many coder use HessianKit in app ? whether it is better than SOAP and JSON?

Tags: iphone

I think that seem is more good performance , but have not use in app.

I have use the kit in a test app, but I found the code seem is not good, some exception does handle , the test app crashed like when connect failed, I have to modify the core code of the kit to solve such problem.

I am not sure whether the lib code is stable ... anyone have experience on this field (choice which solution, XML JSON or other ) ,

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about this question. But here is my 2 cents.

- HessianKit has 40+ new downloads per months.

  - Not super well known.
- It is in use in more than 20 live apps on App Store projects that I know of.

  - Tested in real production, both games and business apps.
- The license is very forgiving.

  - So I have no clue about real total usage out there.

HessianKit pros:

- Works effortlessly with existing Java servers.

  - Just as easy
- Almost non-existing manual glue code.
- Server calls treated *just as* any other method call.

  - Just avoid calls from main thread as with any IO.
- Payload is **small**, as in freaking tiny.

  - On celular network this actually matters.

Hessian cons:

- Communication payload is not human readable.

I am biased, since I am the developer behind HessianKit. If I was to suggest anything else, then I would say JSON. For the following reasons:

- Human readable.
- Buzz-word friendly.